# Why use a Webpack? Is any advantage?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I know CRA (Create-react-app) have a default webpack config files that doing module bundling, mangling, compressing files size, etc..

Is there a performance difference or something advantage when there is a cra webpack and a webpack that I set myself?

Which is good?

Answer (score 1):

There's no performance difference per se, CRA just gives you a standard webpack config that's useful for react. You only need to extend it/create your own webpack config if you need additional features that the CRA config does not support.